# Check if Facebook JS-API app already has been given permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a small script that unlocks some content on a page when a user logs in via Facebook and posts some information on their wall.

I want to avoid any duplicate posts (spam) in the event the user visits the page a second time and repeats the process.

Is there a way of (when asking for the permissions) to tell if they have already been given and therefore skip the sharing part of the script?

Here's my code:

```
$('.preview a').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();  
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.session) {
                        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
                            message: 'Just unlocked the exclusive preview of...',
                            picture: 'http://website.com/share.png',
                            link: 'http://www.website.com',
                            name: 'Name goes here',
                            description: 'Description here'
                            },
                            function(response) {
                                if (!response || response.error) {
                                    alert(response.error);
                                } else {
                                    $('.preview').hide();
                                    $('.clip').show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                },

                {perms:'read_stream,publish_stream'});
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

From 2011 to 2014 a lot of things change..

I made this solution to check for "user_friends" and "publish_actions" permissions, if not allowed the both, force the user to "re-autenticate". The callback method will only be called when all permissions are given.

```
function login(cb,forceAuth) {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status !== 'connected' || forceAuth==true){
            FB.login(function (response) {
                checkPermissions(cb,false);
            }, {scope: 'publish_actions,user_friends'});
        } else {
            checkPermissions(cb);
        }
    });
}

function checkPermissions(cb,forceAuth){
    FB.api(
        "/me/permissions",
        function (response) {
            if (response.data[0]['publish_actions']==undefined || response.data[0]['publish_actions']==0 ||
                response.data[0]['user_friends']==undefined || response.data[0]['user_friends']==0) {
                if (forceAuth!=false)
                    login(cb,true);
            } else {
                cb();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

How to use:

```
login(function () {
    myLogedAndAllowedFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a tutorial about this [here](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-check-if-user-has-certian-permission-facebook-api/22/), and here's an example:

```
FB.api({ method: 'fql.query', query: 'SELECT read_stream,offline_access,publish_stream FROM permissions WHERE uid=me()' }, function(resp) {
    for(var key in resp[0]) {
        if(resp[0][key] === "1")
            console.log(key+' is granted')
        else
            console.log(key+' is not granted')
    }
});
```

There's also a JS REST example there in the article just for reference.

Comment: Thanks but that would give a positive response in both my scenarios. Perhaps a different solution could be to somehow search the user's feed for the link I am sharing and only post if it comes back with no results? Is that possible with FQL?

Comment: @Plasticated: well, the way I would do it is having a table that has the following columns user_id,post_id,action_type where a new record will get inserted once a successful post is made. So the next time the user connect to your app, you'll have that info and change the user experience accordingly.